# How do i prove that the these two definitions of divergence are equivalent?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis, surface-integrals, line-integrals, divergence-operator

In class we were given this definition: $Div (\vec{F}):= lim_{r \rightarrow0} \oint_{C} \vec{F} \cdot \vec{n} \:ds$ (where r is the radius of the circle C and $\vec{n}$ is the outward pointing normal of the curve C).

How do i show that defining divergence in this way also implies that

$Div(\vec{F}) = \partial_1 F_1 + \partial_2 F_2$?

And so on in higher dimensions

Edit: here are my results so far:

$\vec{T} = \frac{dx}{ds} e_x + \frac{dy}{ds} e_y $ which implies for a counter-clockwise (positive?) arc-length-parametrisation
$\vec{n} = \frac{dy}{ds} e_x - \frac{dx}{ds} e_y$ such that

$\operatorname{Div}(\vec{F}) = \lim_{r\to0} \frac{1}{\pi r^2}\oint_{C}\vec{F} \cdot \vec{n} \: ds = \lim_{r\to0} \frac{1}{\pi r^2}\oint_{C} \begin{bmatrix} F_1 \\ F_2 \end{bmatrix} \cdot \begin{bmatrix} \frac{dy}{ds} \\ \frac{dx}{ds} \end{bmatrix} \: ds = \lim_{r\to0} \frac{1}{\pi r^2}\oint_{C} F_1\frac{dy}{ds} + F_2\frac{dx}{ds}  \: ds$

But this still isn't quite right edit2: meant to say this still quite doesn't show what I'm looking for

Comment: Hint: Trying writing the integral in polar coordinates. If $C$ is a circle, what direction is $\vec{n}$ pointing? It works the same way in higher dimensions just with spherical coordinates.

Comment: AHHH THANK YOU that was just what i needed i think

Comment: If you come up with a solution, write it up as an answer to your own question so others can refernce it when they search.

Comment: Will try, haven't solved it yet though

Comment: You can get the proper font and spacing for $\lim$ using `\lim`. For operators that don't have a command of their own, like $\operatorname{Div}$, you can use `\operatorname{Div}`.

Comment: Your edit is right but you make your life way too hard: Use Gauss' theorem $$\oint_{C}\vec{F} \cdot \vec{n} \: ds=\int_B\operatorname{div}F\,dA$$ where $B$ is the ball encircled by $C\,.$ Then realise that this ball has area $\pi r^2\,.$ Divide the RHS by that area and let the ball shrink to zero. What do you get?

Comment: Doesn't this take as given that $div F = \nabla \cdot F$? I see now that most people probably start out with this definition, and then prove it implies that the shrinking circle limit definition is also correct, but how do you prove the implication the other way around? Sorry I'm not trying to be obtuse I'm just a bit confused.

Comment: What is wrong with taking as given that the divergence is $\nabla\cdot F$ and that this divergence satisfies Gauss? I leave it to you to formulate the other way round precisely. It might become a new interesting MSE question.

Comment: @whpowell96 "I believe that the final answer will involve derivatives of things w.r.t. r" that doesn't sound quite right to me, if I convert the integral to polar coordinates we're not integrating along r and theta, we are just integrating along theta and treating r as a constant. At least that is how it has worked out for me so far

Answer (score 1):

Something is wrong. The divergence of $F(x,y)=({x\atop y})$ is two but according to your limit formula
$$
\lim_{r\to 0}\int\limits_{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}=r}F\cdot\hat{\mathbf{n}}\,ds=
\lim_{r\to 0}\;\int_0^{2\pi}r^2\,\,d\theta
=\lim_{r\to 0} \,2\,\pi\,r^2=0\,.
$$
***Hint:***

The correct limit formula is
$$
\operatorname{div}F=\lim_{r\to 0}\;\frac{1}{\pi r^2}\int\limits_{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}=r}F\cdot\hat{\mathbf{n}}\,ds
$$
which we often see as
$$
\operatorname{div}F(x,y)=\lim_{|V|\to 0}\frac{1}{|V|}\int_{C}F\cdot\hat{\mathbf{n}}\,ds
$$ where $|V|$ is the area ("volume") enclosed by $C\,.$ That volume has to shrink to the point $(x,y)\,.$
Hint for proof: Gauss' or Green's theorem.

Comment: I have seen both Gauss' and Green's theorem, howwever I intuited those wouldn't be able to answer my question since both of them seem to rely upon the two definitions of the Div operation to already be proven equivalent, am I correct?

Comment: @Minimo This is very confusing. I showed that your limit definition of divergence gives a wrong result and showed how to fix that. If you don't want to call that limit a divergence because you want to prove that is the divergence call it "limit". Define divergence in the usual way with derivatives and use Gauss' theorem to show that it agrees with the limit. If you have a better proof idea let me know.